# Form 2555 (Foreign earned income exclusion)

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-residency

I am filing my 2019 US tax returns as resident alien, but during the later part of 2019, I paid taxes in India on Indian income. Should I fill out Form 2555 to claim foreign earned income exclusion?

Comment: Has it been 12 months since you left the US? You need to find a 12-month period during which you were outside the US for 330 days in order to pass the Physical Presence Test for the Foreign Earned Income Exclusion.

Comment: Yes. I left the USA more than a year ago.